# Git - SSH - Hosts: How can I delegate different IPs to remote origin, depending on what works each time?

Tags: linux, git, ssh

When at home, `git fetch origin master` should connect over ssh to `git@192.168.xx.xx`.

When on the road, `git fetch origin master` should connect over ssh to `git@xxx.linkpc.net`.

## Possible Solutions

- [Having multiple remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649479/2996101) for the same repository/branch works but git tracks multiple heads unnecessarily. This solution just messes with the beauty.
- Assigning a hostname to remote and comment/uncomment `/etc/hosts` entries to delegate ips is a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15836769/2996101) but includes sudoing and entering the root password which is kind of tedious.
- A per user hosts file is [out of the question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts)
- Writing a script that each time the `origin` is called will delegate the correct ip, [is ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720041/2996101).
- Writing a script that will be executed as root each time a user calls it, seems to be a [marginally fair solution](https://superuser.com/a/440403).

### Question

How could someone tackle with this issue using a solution that -by all means- shall not be considered "of a hackish character"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you are tunneling over SSH, so your `~/.ssh/config` brings a per-user hosts file back into the question, e.g.,

```
Host dynamic-repo-host
    HostName 192.168.xx.xx
    #HostName xxx.linkpc.net
```

Then modify the URL of `origin` as in

```
ssh config remote.origin.url git@dynamic-repo-host
```

Modifying `~/.ssh/config` by hand as appropriate then gives the effect you want.

If you want a completely hands off solution, look into using `Match` in `~/.ssh/config`, but the specific commands to execute will depend on the particulars of the networks on which your local machine runs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you a hint and you can formulate the solution. You might be able to use your [SSH config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5) with the `Match` and `exec` keyword :

> **Match**
>
> Restricts the following declarations (up to the next Host or Match keyword) to be used only when the conditions following the Match keyword are satisfied.
>
> ...
>
> *The **exec** keyword executes the specified command under the user's shell. If the command returns a zero exit status then the condition is
>   considered true.*